Connect TurtoiseHg running on Windows Host machine to repository inside Linux VM
My VM running Linux has the Mercurial repository and so far I do all my HG related things via terminal over SSH.
However, I would like to use TurtoiseHG which is running on my Windows host machine to connect to the VM's mercurial repository.
I do not think I want to clone the repository, I just want TurtoiseHG to be able to interact with the repository which is already established already in the VM.
I'm not sure how to achieve this.
I have searched for any documentation about connecting TurtoiseHG to a remote repository via SSH, but I can't seem to find anything relevant.

Network file share from vm to host. Not safe for multiple users but single user would be fine.
